# Which openings offer the best chances to reach an endgame quickly?

Tags: opening, endgame

If you are strong at endgames, which openings are favorouble for you 
 because they tend to lead quickly to an endgame ?

Comment: As one answer stated below -> none. Your opponent and you will always have a choice, meaning that following scenario will occur: you may offer a trade, or entrance in the "endgame variation" of the opening, but your opponent is the one who then chooses to accept or decline to enter the endgame. I know it sucks, since I prefer endgames as well, but it is a sad truth. I am sorry to disappoint you, but better to learn this lesson here then by losing countless games trying to desperately reach an endgame...

Answer (score 4):

The Berlin comes to mind.

White can avoid this famous endgame, but only at the cost of relinquishing any prospects for an opening advantage.

Generally I have a hard time coming up with *openings* leading to endgames. There are rather *variations* within openings that are endgame prone.

To find variations like the Berlin I advice you to look at the games of Ulf Andersson. He is famous for going into the endgame as quickly as possible.

Comment: It is a false concept that the Berlin leads rapidly to an endgame. The Berlin leads rapidly to a Queenless middlegame which is indeed quite complex

Comment: Well, endgame is a somewhat fuzzy term. But for some reason even the very best players in the world refer to the position after the queen exchange as "Berlin endgame". And in any case, even if exchanging queens doesn't necessarily constitute an endgame, most games in the Berlin quickly reach positions that are without any doubt endgames.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is: none. Even if some variants allow some quick piece exchanging, the other part has always a chance to complicate things.

Also you don't have to fall for the false idea that once the Queens are exchanged the game has reached, or is about to reach shortly, the endgame.